# UITableView indents at the wrong time

Tags: ios, uitableview, indentation

I have a default edit button on the top left of my navigation bar. When it is pressed, the damn table does not show the indentation the first time. When I press "done" it does! How do i fix this?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

}


#pragma mark edit


- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [_tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}



-(void)     tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



}
```

**EDIT**

**Overriding these two methods in the UITableViewCell subclass removes the indentation for me.**

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
```

**So I can now make my own animation.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding these two methods in the UITableViewCell subclass removes the indentation for me.

```
 - (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
 - (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
```

So I can now make my own animation.